# units on x axis after FFT

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

My signal is a static 1D pattern detected by the linear photodiode array with N pixels and pitch p.

What units will I get along the X-axis after FFT to spectrum?

Comment: well, not really a Matlab question...

Comment: @GSRush ... and what units do you have along the x-axis before the FFT spectrum, hmm?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a signal f(x) with unit U depending on variable x with unit V. Then

- the continuous Fourier transform of f has unit UV and depends on a variable with unit 1/V.

  - Example 1: f(x) is a Voltage with x being time. then the Fourier transform has unit Vs (or V/Hz) versus variable 1/s (or Hz).
  - Example 2: f(x) is a power with x being space. Then the FT has unit Wm and the x axis (which is then a wavenumber) unit 1/m (this is probably your case).
- the Discrete Fourier transform (or FFT) has unit U (same as original) and depends on a discrete variable, (which has with unit 1 by definition because it is just a counter).

So the units of the X-Axis of a FFT are 1 (because it is a counter).

I included the continuous Fourier transform, because I suspect that you just confused the FFT (which is just the name of an algorithm for the discrete Fourier transform by the way) with the ordinary (continuous) Fourier transform.

Answer (score 1):

Let me clarify my above question because of the shortage of initial meaningful data.

The question was related with inverse FT of a spatial interferogram (a.k.a. fringe pattern) formed from the optical radiation by a static Fourier-transform spectrometer and detected with a linear photo diode array to reconstruct finally the optical spectrum.

Therefore, the mathematically formal answer "So the units of the X-Axis of a FFT are 1 (because it is a counter)" is absolutely right.