# How to get FFT units for spatial 1D signal?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, sampling, dft

*Note : Answers with dimensions (cy/mm) instead of (Hz) would be greatly appreciated!*

I have looked into [unit of fft(DFT) x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397393/unit-of-fftdft-x-axis) and [units on x axis after FFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130199/units-on-x-axis-after-fft) , but I couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for. So, I decided to write my own question.

I have an object in the real world that has a width of 3mm that scans a bigger object of width 310mm. I can model this as a linear system with a convolution process with a rectangular function of width 3mm as follows:

```
g(x) = f(x) * rect(x/3mm)
```

where `f(x)` is the 310mm object, and `g(x)` is the output of the scanned object. In MATLAB, I'm trying to simulate this effect, so I imported the 310mm object as a high resolution array with each point in the array corresponds to 1mm.

Now, to model the `rect(x/3mm)` I'm thinking of two way to do it, and I'm not sure which one is correct.

1- Is to say that `rect(x/3mm)` is equal to 3 points of the high resolution array, then can be created as a kernel of zeros of the same size as the high resolution object with only 3 point of 1's. Now the actual spacing between the kernel point = 1mm. How can you show the proper FFT scale of this rect(x/3mm) model?

2- I can define in MATLAB

```
d = 3; % in mm
value = 2;
spacing = 0.01;
x = -value: spacing : value - spacing
y = rect(x/d);
```

the second way will provide me with a `rect(x/3mm)` that can be coarsely of finely created depending on spacing or value, but the first way was only 3 points. How can you show the proper FFT scale of this rect(x/3mm) model?

Which of the two methods is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: see my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054363/matlab-fast-fourier-transform-fft-for-time-and-speed/13054749#13054749

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Fourier analysis \ signal processing  theory and not programming 

Comment: I saw your answer, and I know that df*dx*N = 1, then I can plot my answers from -Nyq_rate: Nyq_rate. But the 2 ways I mentioned above can results in different answers. 
I tried to introduce the background before the programming question for better understanding. That's why probably you felt it is off-topic. It is mainly about which way is correct and how to deal with each way in terms of scaling! Thank you :)